# Как получить имя в Laravel

Tags: laravel

Как получить путь у ресурсного маршрута ?

```
Route::get('photos', 'PhotoController')->name('home'); - работает

Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController'); -?
```

Answer (score 2):

Имена будут такими:

```
photos.index                                                  
photos.store
photos.create
photos.show
photos.update
photos.destroy
```

Всю информацию о роутах Вы можете вывести в консоли:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Там будет вся информация, включая url, и HTTP-методы.